# Text Plugin - embedded html

Tags: docpad

text-plugin (https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-text/) seems to escape HTML embedded within markup text.

Isn't the plugin supposed to use "marked" for transformation ... the same way it's done when processing a md document to html (which in that case will happily handle mixed markdown and html data)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to render anything it will use whatever plugin for it you have installed, as it just uses the exact same rendering pipeline as the one inside docpad to do the transformations.

It's strange that the content is being escaped, perhaps an older version of the plugin were the `sanitize` option was true by default (more recent versions it is set to false by default)?

Won't be able to help further unless we see the repo source. Thanks.